# Find N(3) largest number in K(10) numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, compare

I want to find three largest number(area) from 10 numbers(scanf), I wrote this code, but only the largest number is correct when I run it, second and third largest number is wrong. So, I need help. any suggestions? Merry Christmas！

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

int main()
{
        int i,j;
        int area; 
        int maxArea[N]; 
        int empty = N;

     for(j=0;j<10;j=j+1)
     {    
         printf("Input:");
          scanf("%d",&area);
          printf("\n");

         if(empty > 0)
         {
           maxArea[N-empty]=area;

           empty=empty-1;
         }
         else
         {
           for(i=0; i < N; i=i+1)
           {
             if(area>maxArea[i])
             {
               maxArea[i]=area;

               break;
             }
           }
         }
       }
       printf("Area1=%d\n",maxArea[0]);
       printf("Area2=%d\n",maxArea[1]);
       printf("Area3=%d\n",maxArea[2]);
```

}

Comment: Your code flow is totally bizarre.  One way to simplify it would be to read all your 10 elements in one loop and then _exit_ that loop.  Then do whatever computation you want to do on the data you read (including finding the largest 3 elements).  Finding the top 3 elements could just be one pass over the array.  To find more than 3, research the STL... it has algorithms that can help you.

Comment: I don't see anything C++ about the question, so I've removed the tag. Please refrain from including tags that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I am so depressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

int main(){
    int i,j;
    int area; 
    int maxArea[N];

    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
        maxArea[i]=INT_MIN; 

    for(j=0;j<10;++j){    
        printf("Input:");
        scanf("%d",&area);
        printf("\n");
        for(i = 0;i<N && i <= j;++i){
            if(area > maxArea[i]){
                memmove(&maxArea[i+1], &maxArea[i], (N-i-1)*sizeof(*maxArea));
                maxArea[i] = area;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

     printf("Area1=%d\n", maxArea[0]);
     printf("Area2=%d\n", maxArea[1]);
     printf("Area3=%d\n", maxArea[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This's what I want! Thanks!  Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should initialize all the array elements to zero.

Also, your code does not work correctly since you only check for the first element in the array that is lesser than the new element.

If the array has 6, 3, 2 and the new element is 7, then 7 shall pop out 6 from the array and the array shall become 7, 3, 2. Instead it should have been 7, 6, 3.

**You should pop out the lowest number in the array.**

In the general case a `minheap` would be the best resort. (for k largest elements)

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct. pop out the lowest number means?

Comment: @Dashu is the new number is larger than any of the 3 numbers, find the lowest of the 3 numbers and replace that with the new number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I go to try

Answer (score 1):

I just want to show you a different approach, you have to decide for yourself what is easier;

First I initialize `maxArea` with the smallest possible integer. This way I don't need special handling if it does not contain 3 numbers yet. Any number will simply be larger then `MIN_INT`, so it will be replaced automatically.

```
for(i=0; i < N; i++)
{
   maxArea[i]=MIN_INT;
}
```

In the loop, I swap area with the old maximum value, and I keep running the loop, so the old value will be reused for the other max values.

```
for(j=0;j<10;j=j+1)
{    
     printf("Input:");
     scanf("%d",&area);
     printf("\n");

     for(i=0; i < N; i++)
     {
         if(area>maxArea[i])
         {
           // swap both
           int temp=maxArea[i];
           maxArea[i]=area;
           area=temp;
         }
     }
 }
```

Note that this is not very optimized, but it might be better to read what is happening. `maxArea[0]` will always be the largers, `maxArea[1]` the next and so on.

for example if the array is [6, 3, 2], and the new area is 5;

- nothing will happen in the first loop, because 5 is smaller than 6.
- In the second loop (i=1), the array will become [6, 5, 2] and area will be 3.
- In the third loop, the array will become [6, 5, 3], and area will be 2, (but that 2 will not be used any more).